# Accelerometer 'Change in Height' Code PIC

Tags: c++, c, accelerometer, pic

I am carrying out a project which is a device to measure the change in drop height from a cliff and to measure the depth of water to determine whether or not the jump is safe. A rule of thumb states that a ratio of 2:1 is suitable e.g. if the cliff was 10 meters, the water depth would have to be a minimum of 5 meters. The circuitry incorporates the following components:

Microcontroller    PIC18F45K20

Accelerometer      ADXL335

Sonar Transducer   (Salvaged from a 'Lucky Portable Fish Finder')

2 x 1 Watt LED

I am using MPLab Version 8.76 - Pick it 3 Programmer/Debugger

.................................................................................

I am struggeling to utilise the code for this operation and would appreciate it if there were any snippets/sample code out there, especially to measuree the 'change in height' with the accelerometer.

Kindest Regards

Max

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I hope nobody is going to risk his neck to test your device..;) You must be extra careful where human security is involved, especially if you are thinking about product commercialization.

Comment: @Ali Not a duplicate of that, for the reason I mention in my answer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Yes, you are right. Assuming that the device has no initial vertical velocity and the drag force is negligible, your suggestion can give reasonable estimates. Seems like an overkill though to measure height this way. Nevertheless it could work.

Answer (score 1):

Measuring displacement given acceleration is pretty much impossible due to double-integration error.

But, you're in luck since you only want to measure free-fall. Just monitor the accelerometer, and when total acceleration falls below a threshold (that is, gravity goes away), assume that the device is falling at 9.81 m/s<sup>2</sup>. Of course gravity varies from place to place, and terminal velocity kicks in eventually, but I don't suppose that really affects divers.

Just add the accelerometer channels, don't bother calculating an actual vector magnitude. Run it at the highest frequency you can. The formula is `9.81 / ( 2 * freq * freq ) * t * t` where `t` is the number of accelerometer readings of negligible magnitude.

I have no idea how to operate a sonar.

Note that you need to take responsibility for the life of anyone who relies on the device to actually plan a dive.

Comment: Thanks ever so much. I don't suppose you would know how to program this with the PIC18F45K20? The rest of the code I can manage but measuring free fall with the accelerometer using the 3 axis analogue inputs is going to be a 'bit' over my head.

Comment: People who are concerned about any ethical issues, i can assure them that no one will be harmed upon the testing of such a device. A project devoted purely for research :D

Comment: @Max Implementation as code can be done by experimentation. What I'd do is tie the outputs together (the chip has internal resistors so it's OK), then connect them to a single analog comparator. Run the on-chip clock counter at the highest frequency possible. Such a setup could beat the accelerometer's rated frequency, if the rising and falling edges are reliably delayed by the same amount (don't see why not). But, once the physics is done you need to get the outputs off the chip. If you have a setup to read the outputs, you can have fun playing around with the sensors. So work on that first.

Comment: Thanks, will do. I will keep you updated.